# Error while dispatching from onChange event inside the return function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is the onChange event:

```
onChange={(event, newValue) => {
       this.props.changeTabState(newValue)
}}
```

And here is the dispatch to Props:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    changeTabState: (newTabState) => dispatch(changeTabState(newTabState))
})
```

I'm getting an error called 'TypeError: *redux_actions_tab_action__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12*_ is not a function' on the line where I call this.prop.changeTabState.

Here is the initial state:

```
export const TAB_STATE = () => {
  return{
    tab: 0
  }
}

export const TAB_CHANGE = "tab_action"
```

The Tab Action file:

```
import {TAB_CHANGE} from '../utils'

export const changeTabState = (newTabState) => {
  return {
    type : TAB_CHANGE,
    payload : newTabState
  }
}
```

The Tab Reducer file:

```
import { TAB_STATE, TAB_CHANGE } from '../utils'
import _ from 'lodash'

export const tabReducer = (state = TAB_STATE(), action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TAB_CHANGE: {
        let newState = _.cloneDeep(state)
        newState = { ...newState, ...action.payload }
        return newState
    }
  }
  return state
}
```

Comment: Please add some more code to export the class and the file where you are using createStore for more clarification.

Comment: Ok I'll add that in a moment.

Comment: Have added additional code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved the problem by changing the way I import.

Earlier I was importing like this:

```
import * as changeTabState from '../../redux/actions/tab_action'
```

But now I import like this:

```
import {changeTabState} from '../../redux/actions/tab_action'
```

I also changed the state the way I dispatch in onChange to like this:

```
onChange={(event, newTabState) => {
       this.props.changeTabState({tab: newTabState})
     })
 }}
```